# OneHotEncoder - encoding only some of categorical variable columns

Tags: python, scikit-learn, one-hot-encoding

Let's assume that I have a pandas dataframe with the following column names:

- `'age'` (e.g. 33, 26, 51 etc)
- `'seniority'` (e.g. 'junior', 'senior' etc)
- `'gender'` (e.g. 'male', 'female')
- `'salary'` (e.g. 32000, 40000, 64000 etc)

I want to transform the `seniority` categorical variables to one hot encoded values. For this reason I am doing the following:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['seniority'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['seniority'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(categorical_features=[1])
data = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(data.values)
```

But then I am getting this error

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: 'gender'
```

at line

```
data = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(data.values)
```

However, I have explicitly specified that `categorical_features=[1]` so only column 1 (`seniority`) should be considered for this one hot encoding.

How can I fix this error (except for example by dropping the column 'gender')?

I was using `pandas.get_dummies` in the past and I did not have this problem.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think for this case you should stick to `pd.get_dummies`:

```
>>> data
   age seniority  gender  salary
0    1    junior    male       5
1    2    senior  female       6
2    3    junior  female       7

# One hot encode with get_dummies
data = pd.concat((data,pd.get_dummies(data.seniority)),1)

>>> data
   age seniority  gender  salary  junior  senior
0    1    junior    male       5       1       0
1    2    senior  female       6       0       1
2    3    junior  female       7       1       0
```

The problem is that `sklearn`'s `OneHotEncoder` needs to have an array of ints as input. But in the array `data.values`, you still have the string representation of `gender`. You could, if you wanted, just one hot encode the seniority values, but if you want to know the meaning of those features, it's not very nice, you have to pass it the column names manually (which is unfeasible in a lot of cases):

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['seniority'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['seniority'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
data[['junior','senior']] = one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(data['seniority'].values.reshape(-1,1))

>>> data
   age  seniority  gender  salary  junior  senior
0    1          0    male       5     1.0     0.0
1    2          1  female       6     0.0     1.0
2    3          0  female       7     1.0     0.0
```

Or, if the feature names don't matter:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
label_encoder = LabelEncoder()
data['seniority'] = label_encoder.fit_transform(data['seniority'])

from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
one_hot_encoder = OneHotEncoder(sparse=False)
data = pd.concat((data,pd.DataFrame(one_hot_encoder.fit_transform(data['seniority'].values.reshape(-1,1)))),1)

   age  seniority  gender  salary    0    1
0    1          0    male       5  1.0  0.0
1    2          1  female       6  0.0  1.0
2    3          0  female       7  1.0  0.0
```

But in the end, `pd.get_dummies` does the job in a much nicer way (IMO)

Comment: Thanks for your answer (upvote). I will wait a bit to see if there is any better answer and if not I will tick yours as correct.

Comment: `OneHotEncoder` no longer requires the input to be integers. See here:

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html#encoding-categorical-features

Comment: In order for this to work, I had to use brackets instead of parentheses: data = pd.concat([data,pd.get_dummies(data.seniority)],1)